# Fit to curve array not working

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to make a fence and make it fit to a curve as an array but it won't work

Here's the image

[image]

For some reason unknown it multiplies it in a straight line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Fit Curve* option won't make your object follow the curve, it will just adjust the amount of iterations to the curve length. If you want your object to follow a curve, give it a *Curve* modifier after the *Array*. You can keep *Fit Curve* option in the *Array*, it will create the right amount of iterations.

Comment: Thanks a lot that did it for me!! You're a star <3 Ill accept the question in 5 min